# After importing a csv file, extra rows are being created in my sqlite db table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv, import, sqlite, rake-task

I'm importing 17 csv files into my app via rake tasks.  The other files will import fine and not create extra rows, but for some reason this file is creating about 60 empty rows in my database.  The information I'm trying to import is going in fine and it's being associated with it's appropriate tables the way it should.  So if you were to use the app, everything functions properly but its making a mess of my table.

For example, I'm importing 2 rows into the table and right after those two are being created, it's followed by 58 blank rows.  Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can use a conditional statement to keep this from happening and please be specific I'm still relatively new at this.  Thanks

Here is my code:

```
require 'csv'

namespace :import_mat_lists_csv do

task :create_mat_lists => :environment do
    puts "Import Material List"

    csv_text = File.read('c:/rails/thumb/costrecovery/lib/csv_import/mat_lists.csv')
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
    csv.each_with_index do |row,index|
        row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
        MatList.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
        matlist = MatList.last
        if @report_incident_hash.key?(matlist.report_nr)
            matlist.incident_id = "#{@report_incident_hash[matlist.report_nr]}"
        end

        #matlist.timesheet_id = @timesheet_id_array[index]
        matlist.save
    end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, when I went to attach my csv file I noticed some major issues which I should've caught in the first place.  Some how my csv file got some fields added to it...I can't believe I didn't catch this, but thanks.

Comment: No problem, try the `row.join.blank?` should do the evaluation you want too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this, but perhaps the easiest would be to add:

```
unless row.join.blank?
```

Your code would read:

```
csv.each_with_index do |row,index|
  unless row.join.blank?
    row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
    MatList.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
    matlist = MatList.last

    if @report_incident_hash.key?(matlist.report_nr)
      matlist.incident_id = "#{@report_incident_hash[matlist.report_nr]}"
    end

    #matlist.timesheet_id = @timesheet_id_array[index]
    matlist.save
  end
end
```